# Refresh paginate menu links() after change items per page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pagination

I have blade.php with table. I have a menu that allows you to choose how many items to display on the page.
I also have a page number selection menu ( {{ $ingredients->links() }} ). Unfortunately, this only works well when the number of elements per page is the default. When I change the number of items, the page number selection menu does not update.

**index.blade.php**

```
<a class="w-20 items-actual-count text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
   data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">10</a>
<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdown"
     class="items-count z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700"
     aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" x-placement="bottom-end"
     style="will-change: transform; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(120px, 48px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <a href="#"
       class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">10</a>
    <a href="#"
       class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">20</a>
    <a href="#"
       class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">50</a>
    <a href="#"
       class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">100</a>
</div>
<div id="pagination-container">
    {{ $ingredients->links() }}
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(function() {
    $('div.items-count a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('a.items-actual-count').text($(this).text());
        $('#dropdown').removeClass('block').addClass('hidden');
        getItems($(this).text());
    });

    $('a#filter-button').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getItems($('a.items-actual-count').text());
    });

    function getItems(paginate) {
        const form = $('form#sidebar-filter').serialize();
        console.log(form)
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "ingredients/",
            data: form + "&" + $.param({paginate: paginate}),
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                $('tbody#ingredients-list').empty();
                $.each(response.data, function (index, ingredient) {
                    const html = '<tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">' +
                        '                   <th scope="row"' +
                        '                       class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">' +
                                                    ingredient.name +
                        '                   </th>' +
                        '                   <td class="px-6 py-4">' +
                                                ingredient.category +
                        '                   </td>' +
                        '                   <td class="px-6 py-4">' +
                                                ingredient.unit +
                        '                   </td>' +
                        '                   <td class="px-6 py-4">' +
                                                ingredient.calories +
                        '                   </td>' +
                        '                   <td class="px-6 py-4">' +
                        '                       <a href="#"' +
                        '                          class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">Edit</a>' +
                        '                   </td>' +
                        '                 </tr>';
                    $('tbody#ingredients-list').append(html);
                });

                const paginationHtml = response.links;
                $('div#pagination-container').html(paginationHtml);
            });
    }
});
```

**IngredientController.php**

````
public function index(Request $request): View|Application|Factory|JsonResponse
    {
        $filters = $request->query('filter');
        $paginate = $request->query('paginate') ?? 10;
        $query = Ingredient::query();
        if (!is_null($filters) && isset($filters['categories'])) {
            $query = $query->whereIn('category', $filters['categories']);
        }

        $ingredients = $query->paginate($paginate);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($ingredients);
        }

        return view('ingredients.index', [
            'ingredients' => $ingredients,
            'categories' => Ingredient::distinct('category')->pluck('category')
        ]);
    }```
````

Comment: In the case of your ajax call `response.links` is `json` not html. it is not the same as your `{{ $ingredients->links() }}` call in php.